# Duplicate values in p:selectOneMenu

Tags: primefaces

Currently I have a Primefaces selectOneMenu to display values direct from the database. However due to it being repeated multiple times in the database, these values are being duplicated multiple times. Once for each instance in the database. Is there any way to retrieve these values and only display one of each?

I have provided the code for the selectOneMenu below, if any more is required I will add it.

```
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{addOrderBean.state}" id="state">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=" "/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{ordersBean.orders}" var="order" itemLabel="#{order.state}" itemValue="#{order.state}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Here is an image to display what I mean in case I havent explained it very well:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, you have repeated data on DataBase, but you wonna show only distinct datat on `selectOneMenu` ?

Comment: Yes exactly and I would like to be able to do it without having to create a seperate db table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `SQL` query, for distinct states on your state table, and call the result on `ordersBean.orders` method.

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'STATE TABLE'.state FROM 'STATE TABLE';
```

Comment: Ah ok so the only way to do it is through SQL?

Comment: Well, i think is the best way, because JSF is only for View layer. But you can create som method that removes repeated values from a `List`. I prefer to let the DBMS do this

Comment: Ok sounds like the best plan. Thank you @ColdHack